# Highchart dynamic data by real quotestream

Tags: highcharts

i would like do make highchart like this:
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

The data will be received realtime.

First time i pull data (quote and timestamp).
After this the data will be pushed.

My code:

```
//drow chart - pull
var highChart = function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],

            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
            },
            title : {
                text : 'Intraday chart'
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series : [{
                name : 'DAX DATA',
                data : 
            }]
       });
    }          

    var setHighChart = function(lastPriceTimestamp,lastPrice) {
        highChart.series[0].setData([lastPriceTimestamp,lastPrice]);
     };
```

...

```
//push data    
setHighChart(lastPriceTimestamp,lastPrice);
```

Maby you could help me

thx

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How can i set the data. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in setHighChart(lastPriceTimestamp,lastPrice);

Comment: Error is printed, because you refer to highChart variable which is function instead of serie. To have reference to serie you should use : var chart =   $('#container').highcharts(); chart.series[0].setData([lastPriceTimestamp,lastPrice]);

Comment: thx- now the error is: Unhandled rejection TypeError: $(...).highchart is not a function

Comment: Could you recraete your example as live demo ? For example on jsfiddle.net?